# which qt file to download to build android and ios app?

Tags: android, ios, qt, download

I got crazy by so many qt download files. Basically, I want to build an Android app and an IOS app from a simple widget project(the project contains only a browser widget) on Windows without needing to install MSVC.

I found so many files on download.qt.io like:
qt-opensource-windows-x86-pdb-files-uwp-5.10.0.zip
qt-opensource-windows-x86-pdb-files-desktop-5.10.0.zip
I do not know what "PDB" "UWP" stand for. Finally I found this file:
http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.8/5.8.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.8.0.exe
Because the name contains "android", I think it can be used to build android app. But after I installed this qt, the latest Android Studio which downloaded the latest Android SDK(and I even downloaded a previous version (24) using the sdk manager in Android Studio because I read an article saying you should use SDK version 25.2 or earlier version if you use Qt 5.9 or earlier version.),the latest android ndk, and jdk 11.0.1, I still met problem when creating a project. In the "Kit Selection" step, it says "Android has not been configured. Create Android kits." Then I specified the JDK location, Android SDK location, Android NDK location,and I chose "Use Gradle instead of Ant", but it says "Qt versions for 2 architectures are missing'. I went to Options/Build&Run/Qt Versions and found there are exclamation marks before the two auto-detected Qt versions: "Qt 5.8.0 for Android armv7" and "Qt 5.8.0 for Android x86". The other Qt version "Qt5.8.0 MinGW 32bit", however, looks good.

So, did I install the wrong Qt file? There is no "android" in file names of the latest version(5.11) of the Qt download files. Does it mean the latest Qt does not support Android? The previous Qt file  http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.8/5.8.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.8.0.exe has "android" in it, but since it does not include any android compiler in it, what does the "android" mean?

Please tell me the exact files I need to download to build the Android app and the IOS app. Thanks!

**Update:**

According to @navylover 's suggestion, I upgrade Qt to the latest version 5.11.2. The Android settings are almost ok:java settings are ok, Android SDK tools installed, Platform tools installed, Build tools installed, Android NDK ok. The only failure is Platform SDK not installed.  It says "missing android sdk packages. Android sdk installation is missing necessary packages. Do you want to install the missing packages?" If I click "Yes", nothing happens. I don't know how Qt checks if Platform SDK is installed or not. I think Platform SDK has already been installed with other sdk tools when I installed Android Studio. Now the installed Android SDK is Android 9.0(Pie). Is it not compatible with Qt 5.11.2?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you update QT version to latest. After that, you could read official docs:

[Getting Started with Qt for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) and [Connecting Android Devices](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html).

There are no resource useful than these refs.

Comment: I would have downloaded the latest Qt (5.11) from here: http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.2/.  But I could not find the "android" in the file names so I thought it does not support Android?

Comment: so what file should I download and install?  qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.2.exe, qt-opensource-windows-x86-pdb-files-desktop-5.11.2.7z, or qt-opensource-windows-x86-pdb-files-uwp-5.11.2.7z?

Comment: If you click down from official website, it will down a web installer based your Operation System.

Comment: " qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.2.exe" If you use Windows OS

Comment: I've installed qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.2.exe but the problem persists. It says "missing android sdk packages. Android sdk installation is missing necessary packages. Do you want to install the missing packages?" If I click "Yes", nothing happens.